# Unit testing with Moq - Manipulate Ref Parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit, .net-7.0

I'm writing Unit Tests in the xUnit Framework and have the scenario that i like to handle and manipulate a ref Parameter.

My code so far:

```cs
public interface IBar
{
  public void ManipulateRefParam(ref Foo foo);
}

public class Foo
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  // and so on...
}
```

```cs
// Test Method:
delegate void MockManipulateRefParamCallBack(ref Foo foo);

[Fact]
public void TestSomething()
{
  Mock<IBar> mock = new Mock<IBar>();
  mock.Setup(x => x.ManipulateRefParam(ref It.Ref<Foo>.IsAny))
  .Callback(new MockManipulateRefParamCallBack(
  (ref Foo foo) => {foo = new Foo(); foo.Name = "Foo"})); 

}
```

My final goal is extracting the `ref It.Ref<Foo>.IsAny` parameter, manipulate and parse it to the Callback/Delegate Function.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test here?

Comment: The initialization process for my object. Some data is coming from the appsettings and other data from a sql database. The mockobject should mock the sql part.

Comment: Don't get what you want. Mocking means defining when something goes in a method what is returned. So when 'a'  comes in that 'b' should go out. Not how 'a' is transformed into 'b'. That is something for an implementation not a mock.

Comment: Yeah, the 'b' should go out part is my problem. I try to avoid to create a brand new 'b' because it would be undiserable much effort. Instead I would like to use the outcome from It.Ref<Foo>.IsAny as base for 'b'

Comment: Then create a Foo beforehand use that in the setup and use that instance in the callback as source for the new instance?  Just don't use those IsAny stuff as you obviously don't want 'any' but something specific you can use to change/recreate.

Comment: Yeah, but the IsAny part just delivers the exact thing I need at this point... Creating Foo beforehand is as I already mentioned undesirable much effort.